# If conditional | Dataframe | Key error: 12690

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have a dataframe with a lot of columns, but in this case I am trying to create an if conditional just for one of them.
The idea is compare one row with the previous one to check if they are equal. But the code it doesn't work.

```
    Proyectonevera2['CodProducto']
```

Out:

```
0        10390792
1        10390792
2        10390792
3        10390792
4        10390792
           ...   
12685    10229147
12686    10229147
12687    10229147
12688    10229147
12689    10229147
Name: CodProducto, Length: 12690, dtype: object
```

The column is called "CodProducto" and the type is object

```
    for i in range(0,len(Proyectonevera2)):
        if Proyectonevera2.loc[i+1,'CodProducto'] == Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'CodProducto']:
           Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Prueba'] = 1
        else:
           Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Prueba'] = 0
```

But when I run the code, it appears this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 12690

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17980/3964080695.py in <module>
      1 for i in range(0,len(Proyectonevera2)):
----> 2     if Proyectonevera2.loc[i+1,'CodProducto'] == Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'CodProducto']:
      3         Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Prueba'] = 1
      4     else:
      5         Proyectonevera2.loc[i,'Prueba'] = 0

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    923                 with suppress(KeyError, IndexError):
    924                     return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
--> 925             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
    926         else:
    927             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1098     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: tuple):
   1099         with suppress(IndexingError):
-> 1100             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
   1101 
   1102         # no multi-index, so validate all of the indexers

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_lowerdim(self, tup)
    836                 # We don't need to check for tuples here because those are
    837                 #  caught by the _is_nested_tuple_indexer check above.
--> 838                 section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
    839 
    840                 # We should never have a scalar section here, because

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1162         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1163         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1164         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1165 
   1166     def _get_slice_axis(self, slice_obj: slice, axis: int):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_label(self, label, axis)
   1111     def _get_label(self, label, axis: int):
   1112         # GH#5667 this will fail if the label is not present in the axis.
-> 1113         return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)
   1114 
   1115     def _handle_lowerdim_multi_index_axis0(self, tup: tuple):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3774                 raise TypeError(f"Expected label or tuple of labels, got {key}") from e
   3775         else:
-> 3776             loc = index.get_loc(key)
   3777 
   3778             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 12690
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to do that:

```py
Proyectonevera2['Prueba'] = (Proyectonevera2['CodProducto'] == Proyectonevera2['CodProducto'].shift()).astype('int')
```